# automatically extract aws keys using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have been provided to access aws and get credentials manaully i,e to copy access_key_id,secret_access_key,session_token this will expire every one hour. I am using these credentials to extract information from Route53. I want to automate and get access_key_id,secret_access_key,session_token instead of manually copying to the script. I would like to understand is there any way to do this automation..

Comment: Are you running this app on an AWS compute platform and is it launched with an IAM role? If so, the credentials will be auto-refreshed. If not, and all you have are STS credentials (access key, secret key, and session token) then they typically cannot be used to refresh themselves.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291428/14843902) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The process of refreshing tokens are documented here:
[Auto-refresh AWS Tokens Using IAM Role and boto3](https://dev.to/li_chastina/auto-refresh-aws-tokens-using-iam-role-and-boto3-2cjf)

It is poorly documented in boto documentation but this could help